# Задать структуру в json

Tags: javascript, json, структуры

Хочу задать такую структуру хранения в json

```
"global1": [{

    "t1": [{
        "productName": "товар1",
        "quantity": 1
    }],
    "t2": [{
        "productName": "товар2",
        "quantity": 1
    }]
}]
```

онлайн валидаторы пишут ошибку
Не могу понять,я косячу в синтаксисе или в логике, если так делать

```
{

    "t1": [{
        "productName": "товар1",
        "quantity": 1
    }],
    "t2": [{
        "productName": "товар2",
        "quantity": 1
    }]
}
```

Все валидно

Comment: Потому-что онлайн валидтор расчитывает, что он бдет "без имени". Надо обернуть в {}

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [стандарту](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) данные в json представляют собой:

- Объекты { ... }
- Массивы [ ... ]
- Значения одного из типов:

  - строки в двойных кавычках,
  - число,
  - логическое значение true/false,
  - null.

Ваш первый пример не является ни одним из вышеперечисленных. Второй ваш пример - это объект.